# requires ext-intl * php

Tags: php, xampp, lampp, libphonenumber

I am using UBUNTU 14.04 and with xampp installed.

however, I am having issue download package from

https://github.com/giggsey/libphonenumber-for-php. I have got the composer installed as well.
created `composer.json` file

When I run `php composer.phar install` I received following error

```
  Problem 1
    - giggsey/libphonenumber-for-php 6.2.2 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
    - giggsey/libphonenumber-for-php 6.2.1 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
    - giggsey/libphonenumber-for-php 6.2.0.1 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
    - giggsey/libphonenumber-for-php 6.2 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
    - giggsey/libphonenumber-for-php 6.1.1 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
    - giggsey/libphonenumber-for-php 6.1 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
    - giggsey/libphonenumber-for-php 6.0 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
    - Installation request for giggsey/libphonenumber-for-php ~6.0 -> satisfiable by giggsey/libphonenumber-for-php[6.0, 6.1, 6.1.1, 6.2, 6.2.0.1, 6.2.1, 6.2.2].
```

Answer (score 2):

You can install the intl extension via apt-get:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-intl
```

Restart your server after the installation completes:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```